# nginx not responding to changes to sites-available

Tags: nginx

My sites-enabled and sites-available are symlinked. The sites-enabled are included in the nginx configuration file. Yet when I make changes to a sites-available file, nginx doesn't change the way it responds to requests. This is even after I've restarted nginx.

The specific issue is that I used to forward traffic from the root url to a www version like so:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name revolution.cheap;
  return 301 http://www.revolution.cheap$request_uri;
}

server{
  listen 80;
  server_name www.revolution.cheap;
  passenger_enabled on;
  root /var/www/revolution/public;
}
```

Yet even after commenting out the first entry, requests continue being redirected to www.revolution.cheap. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser history, cache, etc,?

Comment: I have. Any other suggestions?